# How do I access the latest value of state using useSelector after dispatching an action in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a screen in a React-Native project which essentially just renders a loading icon whilst fetching data from the server, before then taking the user to the main screen. The first function `getPrivateKey()` will return the private key and store it using redux in the state, and the next function `connectWithKey()` will then use that key to connect.

The issue I'm facing is that when `connectWithkey()` runs, it's using the initial, empty value of the private key, not the updated value. Here's the code, and apologies if I'm being stupid it's been a long day :(

```
export default DataLoader = props => {
  //private key - this should, in theory, update after getPrivateKey()
  const privateKey = useSelector(({ main }) => main.privateKey);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const configure = async () => {
      //this will update the private key
      await getPrivateKey();

      //this should use the new private key from useSelector, but instead is using the initialised empty object
      await connectWithKey();

      props.navigation.navigate('MainScreen');
    };
    configure();
  }, []);

//.... more code below....
```

I've tried adding privateKey into the array dependencies which just caused an infinite loop, and I've checked that the value has updated in the redux store - so I'm a bit lost! In essence, it appears that the useSelector hook isn't getting a fresh value. Any help would be very much appreciated  Thanks!

EDIT - added more code upon request

```
const getPrivateKey = async () => {
  const privKey = await fetchKeyFromServer();
  dispatch({
   type: 'UPDATE',
   value: privKey 
  });
};

const connectWithkey = async () => {
  //the privateKey here should be the updated value from useSelector
  await connectToServer(privateKey)
};
```

Comment: It causes an infinite loop because you're updating and using a variable in the same component. You update the variable (via a dispatch or something) which causes all things that select it from the store to rerender, which your component is one of them, so your component rerenders and in the process updates the variable....

Comment: Hi Adam - thanks a load for  your reply! That makes complete sense, I see now that udpating it causes a rerender, so the component rerenders, udpates the variable and boom repetition... I'm only finding that there is an infinite loop when I include privateKey in the variable however, not what I've listed above - it just refers to the old value from useSelector - do you have any idea how i'd use the recent value?

Comment: It basically seems that function A needs to run to put something into redux store, but then function B requires that value from the store, and it's using the value from before A changed it.

Comment: It's very simple - do the work in separate components.

Comment: Think about it like this - you have tightly tied together the use of the privateKey and it's update - whenever the privateKey updates you request a new privateKey. This is NOT the logic that you want to happen. When, precisely, do you want to update the privateKey?

Comment: So the only way to access an updated store value between two function calls is through component separation? I'm happy to do this but I presumed there would be another way or I was missing something? Thanks again for your swift reply.

Comment: There must be some other piece of information that you can use to determine if you actually need to request an update to the provateKey other than the key itself. If that piece of information tells you that you don’t need to update the key, then don’t do it

Comment: So essentially, getPrivateKey() gets the key from the server and stores it in redux. To be able so actually sign in, the user then has to use that key to connect - so I need to update the store in function A, and then retrieve the updated value, but const privateKey = useSelector(... ) doesn't appear to be updating - sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: originally the privateKey in the store is empty, when the user creates an account it calls getPrivateKey(), which dumps it in the store - then the user can grab this from the store and sign in with connectWithKey()

Comment: The selector works just fine, it’s probably because you haven’t actually updated the key in the store after you’ve gotten a new one. But when you do that, you’re back into infinite loop mode unless you determine exactly when you need to update the privateKey

Comment: You'll have to show more at least some of the code with `getPrivateKey` to get a better picture of what's going on.

Comment: I've update the code Adam thanks - after I dispatch the action I print the value of the new state in the reducer, and it does appear to be updating it hence my confusion.

Comment: Your `connectWithKey` from is telling me exactly what's going on - you aren't supplying it as a parameter to that function so you must have a `let privateKey` in the top of that file somewhere as you tried to avoid your infinite loop situation.

Comment: privateKey is the global constant defined with useSelector isn't it? I have it defined at the top as a constant and am then utilitising this value.

Comment: My original comment still stands you can get the privateKey and use the privateKey **in the same component (or hook)**. They need to be separated. `getPrivateKey` is NOT dependent upon the privateKey as you've illustrated in your code, but `connectWithKey` IS dependent upon the privateKey. Could be as simple as creating two `useEffect` hooks. But you still haven't answered the question - when, precisely, do you need to update the privateKey?

Comment: `privateKey` is not a **global** constant - it's defined within the body of this functional component. You're code is very confused, and I get it, understanding react hooks is hard (until you get it and then it's easy), but there's probably no way to fix this until you show a more of your code together, like in a sandbox, it doesn't matter if the api calls don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `getPrivateKey` function is a thunk, but you are not *dispatching* it ? And there is nothing stopping you from returning values from thunks.

```
const getPrivateKey = async (dispatch) => {
  const privKey = await fetchKeyFromServer();
  dispatch({
   type: 'UPDATE',
   value: privKey 
  });
  return privKey // return the key here to whoever wants to use the value immediately.
};
```

Then in your `useEffect` in the component you can use the return value easily :)

```
useEffect(() => {
    const configure = async () => {
      //make sure you 'dispatch' this thunk
      const key = await dispatch(getPrivateKey());

      // pass the key
      await dispatch(connectWithKey(key));
      ...
    };
    ....
  }, []);
```

The code above assumes that the `connectWithKey` is a thunk too. If so, you can design the thunk in a way that it either uses the passed value or reads it from the redux store.

```
const connectWithkey = (privateKey: passedPrivateKey) = async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const state = getState();
  let privateKey = state.whatever.the.path.is.to.privateKey;

  // use the passed private key if it is present.
  if (passedPrivateKey) {
    privateKey = passedPrivateKey;
  }

  await connectToServer(privateKey)
};
```

I have used this approach several times in my app. This way you do not need to rely on the state in the selector. And should you choose to rely on that state, the dependencies of your `useEffect` should update accordingly. Right now it is an empty array, and that is why the effect doesn't run again on any state changes (it is acting like the `componentDidMount` lifecycle function).

```
const privateKey = useSelector(({ main }) => main.privateKey);

useEffect(() => {
 await getPrivateKey();

 if (privateKey) {
   await connectWithKey();
 }
}, [privateKey]);
```

This way your hook re-runs everytime `privateKey` state changes. You might need to have some sort of condition for your `connectWithKey` thunk though, so that it doesn't run if the key is null.